How to return number placement based on criteria from a table?
I've run into an issue that I can't quite figure out. I need to return the placement of a list of values based on a separate criteria.
I have a table that looks like this:

I'm looking for a way to fill in the place column automatically with a formula. I've gotten as far as:
=LET(
data,$B$3:$D$10,
gender_col,2,total_col,3,
f,FILTER(data,CHOOSECOLS(data,gender_col)=$C3),
s,SORT(f,total_col,-1),
c,CHOOSECOLS(s,3),
c
)

This sorts the totals in descending order, but I haven't figured out how to return the placement.

=MAP(B2:B9,C2:C9,LAMBDA(b,c,SUM(N(FILTER(C2:C9,B2:B9=b)>c))+1))
Or if you want to exclude above 3:
=MAP(B2:B9,C2:C9,LAMBDA(b,c,LET(s,SUM(N(FILTER(C2:C9,B2:B9=b)>c))+1,IF(s<4,s,""))))

@MayukhBhattacharya No, I actually assumed it shouldn't, since OP filtered on it in his own attempt the sorting doesn't matter, but each gender has it's own "ranking"

@MayukhBhattacharya with my testing this method works if the data is sorted only on the name column, intermixing the gender.

Not really sir, please try the intermixing once, and see if you find dupe rankings or not. Don't think OP is looking for that.

looks good to me:https://imgur.com/a/ayE8G1w

I get the same as Scott. Not sure if I understand correctly.

Ah I get it, if there are two m with the same total then the Place is duplicated and one place is skipped.

That's true actually.

@ScottCraner =MAP(B2:B9,C2:C9,LAMBDA(b,c,LET(s,SUM(N(FILTER(C2:C9,B2:B9=b)>c))+1,IF(s<4,s,"")))) will rank same score/gender on same rank and skip next rank instead of previous rank. I think that's a better way to cope with duplicates.

yup, just deleted my exact duplicate comment.

And edited it in my answer

This actually worked initially for my needs. Unfortunately, my requirements have changed. I've been asked to use Google Sheets instead of Excel, which makes this much more difficult.

@Harlan The methodology I provided in my answer will also work in Sheets, although you may want to format that column as number before entering the formula.

If your data is in a Table, you can enter this formula in the first cell of the Place column and it will auto-populate down the rest of the column.
Prior sorting is not required unless you wish it for other reasons
=LET(
    r, XMATCH(
        C2,
        SORT(FILTER($C$2:$C$9, B2 = $B$2:$B$9), 1, -1),
        -1,
        -1
    ),
    IF(r <= 3, r, "")



Here is one way of achieving the desired output(Without LAMBDA() iteration ):


=LET(
     _Data, A15:C22,
     _Gender, INDEX(_Data,,2),
     _Male, FILTER(_Data,_Gender="m"),
     _SortedM, HSTACK(SORT(_Male,3,-1),SEQUENCE(ROWS(_Male))),
     _Female, FILTER(_Data,_Gender="f"),
     _SortedF, HSTACK(SORT(_Female,3,-1),SEQUENCE(ROWS(_Female))),
     _Place, VLOOKUP(TAKE(_Data,,1),CHOOSECOLS(VSTACK(_SortedM,_SortedF),1,-1),2,0),
     IF(_Place=4,"",_Place))


Older Method:
=REDUCE("Place",UNIQUE(B15:B22),LAMBDA(a,b,
 LET(c,FILTER(C15:C22,B15:B22=b),
 d,MATCH(c,SORT(c,,-1),0),
 VSTACK(a,IF(d<4,d,"")))))



Does this assume that the lists of m and f are stacked and not intermixed?

@ScottCraner Sir it wont work actually then, works only when stacked! also in that respect the other answer will not work as well.

Rank Top N Amounts Per Category
N        - top
Amounts  - total
Category - gender


=LET(data,A2:C9,gender_col,2,total_col,3,top,3,
    g,CHOOSECOLS(data,gender_col),
    d,HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(g)),g,CHOOSECOLS(data,total_col)),
    sr,DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(g),LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
        s,TAKE(SORT(FILTER(d,g=r),3,-1),,1),
        rs,ROWS(s),
        ra,EXPAND(SEQUENCE(IF(rs<top,rs,top)),rs,,""),
        VSTACK(rr,HSTACK(ra,s))))),1),
    r,SORTBY(TAKE(sr,,1),DROP(sr,,1)),
    r)


This is an efficient way to use on larger datasets (10k, 100k).
If there are fewer category rows than top, it will rank only those.
It allows more than two categories (genders). Adding more categories means adding more stacks inside REDUCE which will decrease efficiency.


With COUNTIFS
=LET(data, $B$3:$D$10, gender_col, 2, total_col, 3,
rank_within, COUNTIFS(
INDEX(data, 0, gender_col), INDEX(data, 0, gender_col),
INDEX(data, 0, total_col), ">" & INDEX(data, 0, total_col))+1,
VSTACK("Place", IF(rank_within > 3, "", rank_within)))



I wanted to see whether we could use RANK.EQ, but it required reference as second parameter. When used with INDEX it required a contiguous range, since I didn't want to assume it here, I looked for an alternative, and saw that COUNTIFS could be used.
